# Help with seperable diff eq

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem is $dy/dx=.7y$, initial condition $y(0)=-7.$

$$dy/.7y=dx$$
or
$$dy/y=.7x$$

then integrate getting

$$\ln y=.7x$$

$$y=e^{.7x}+C$$

I am definitely doing something wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

$$y=Ae^{.7x}\\
-7=Ae^0\\
-7=A$$
so -7e^(.7x) is correct, thank you

Comment: First, it should be $dy/y=.7\,dx$, not $.7x$. Then it should be $\ln y = .7x +C_0$ so $y=Ce^{.7x}$ where $C=e^{C_0}$.

Answer (score 0):

You should have $dy/y = .7\, dx$, so $\ln|y| = .7x + C$, and then $y = Ae^{.7x}$. The condition $y(0) = -7$ implies $A = -7$. So $y = -7e^{.7x}$.

Comment: only thing im confused on is if I get rid of the ln I would get e^(.7x+C) How does it go from this to Ae^(.7x)?

Comment: @Alex please explain more clearly where you're confused. Are you having trouble with the last step?

Comment: just the step going from lny=.7x+C to y=Ae^(.7x)

Comment: Sure @Alex. From that step, you have $e^{\ln y} = e^{.7x + C} = e^C e^{.7x}$. So $y = e^C e^{.7x}$. Letting $A = e^C$, you get $y = Ae^{.7x}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\ln y=7x+C$$

You must add $C$ in the very step of integration, not later.